# Dazzled and confused about xparse and LaTeX3 Booleans

Tags: latex3, expl3, xparse

I'm just starting my journey with `LaTeX3/expl3`, and although fascinated by the great work that the `LaTeX3` team is doing, and by the enormous difference it brings about with respect to "classical" (La)TeX programming (to me it's such a nice experience that I'll try to stay within its domains as much as possible), I'm still a bit confused on some points. One of those has to do with the `\*DocumentCommand` family introduced by the `xparse` package.

So far I had been using the members of this family embedded in a conventional `LaTeX2e` setting, just toying around with their rich parameter-setting structure and, some mishaps out of lack of practice aside, had no trouble. But now I'm getting eager at having `LaTeX3` in my TeX-based work, and I'm trying to embed `expl3` code in commands created resorting to the `xparse` facilities. This is where my trouble starts. Well, maybe this particular issue is not related at all with `xparse` but with `LaTeX3` Booleans, or expansion, or whatever...

Banter enough. This is a small snippet from a real-life working project (not pretending by any means that what follows is good `LaTeX3/expl3` practice):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xparse,l3keys2e} 

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bool_new:N {c}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bool_if:NTF {cTF}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bool_set_true:N {c}

\tl_const:Nn \c_prefix_tl {g_amod} 
\tl_const:Nn \c_postfix_tl {_bool} 

% Booleans making
\NewDocumentCommand\MakeBool { m }
 { 
    \bool_new:c 
    { \tl_use:N \c_prefix_tl { #1 } \tl_use:N \c_postfix_tl }
 }

% Setting Booleans to True
\NewDocumentCommand\SetTBool { m } 
 {
    \bool_set_true:c
    { \tl_use:N \c_prefix_tl { #1 } \tl_use:N \c_postfix_tl }
 }

% Typing Boolean value
\NewDocumentCommand\ShowValBool { m } 
 { 
    \bool_if:cTF 
    { \tl_use:N \c_prefix_tl { #1 } \tl_use:N \c_postfix_tl } 
    { true } { false }
 }

\MakeBool{columns} % Create a Boolean \g_amod_columns_bool

% l3keys defining and setting
\keys_define:nn { amod }
 {
    columns .bool_set:N = \g_amod_columns_bool
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\DocumentSetup { +m }
 { \keys_set:nn { amod } {#1} }

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \DocumentSetup{ columns = false }
}

\begin{document}
\ShowValBool { columns }% False from l3keys 
\par
\SetTBool { columns }% set to True 
\ShowValBool { columns }% True from above command 
\par % Yes, what comes is ugly enough, but just to check...
\bool_if:cTF% raw expl3 code to check Boolean value. Should return True  
   { g_amod_columns_bool }
   { True } { False }
\end{document}

% And, for a terrible ending...
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The problem is that I'm gettting `False True False`, whereas I would expect `False True True`. What is going on here? What is it that I'm missing or skipping?

Comment: I'll try analyzing the code, but at first sight the `{ #1 }` after `\c_prefix_tl` should lose the braces.

Comment: @egreg: I've just removed those braces, but the issue remains. I get the same result.

Comment: Hm. your question sounds a bit odd. You get false true true and expect false true true. So where is the problem? Beside this I get the correct result if I remove the braces as suggested by egreg in various place and add the missing underscore in the definition of the prefix `\tl_const:Nn \c_prefix_tl {g_amod_}` (I found out that the underscore is missing by adding `\edef\test{\tl_use:N \c_prefix_tl  #1  \tl_use:N \c_postfix_tl }
    \show\test`  to the MakeBool command.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The first was a mistake on my side, I've amended it in my OP. As for the second... yes, I'm going to check, but I guess that's where the problem was; the underscore was missing...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Checked. Blame it on the underscore. So it was a most trivial thing after all... Should you provide an answer, should we close the OP and forget there was ever such a question...? ;-)

Comment: Don't use `\c_prefix_tl` nor `\c_postfix_tl`: use explicit prefixes. You're also mixing global and local, which is wrong: if a variable is prefixed `g_`, it's always to be managed as global.

Comment: @egreg: I appreciate the remarks. I get the second point, but I'm not so sure about the first one. I'm trying to make the command as general as possible in order to set a family of Booleans with the same prefix and suffix (my own terminology here). In that way, if I want to move on to another prefix or suffix I don't need to patch the command. Any suggestions are more than welcome, though.

Comment: BTW: the `c` variants you're creating already exist

Comment: @cgnieder: Oh, good. Yes, I do need to inspect the ``interface3`` doc more closely. That was just for a start with ``LaTeX3/expl3``; I still have everything to learn about it.

Comment: @Marcos The suffix for a boolean *should* be `_bool`, so it doesn't make sense to have a token list for it. Prefixes should also be “unique” for a set of macros, in order to help minimizing conflicts; hence having a variable for them is not good programming, in my opinion.

Comment: @cgnieder Those variants indeed exist, but it doesn't harm “recreating” them; it's just a tiny overhead.

Comment: @egreg I know, which is why my comment was only a »BTW«

Comment: @egreg: Right. The suffix thing came actually from a token list concatenating procedure that I have not included in my OP. In the future, I'll take into account your remark on the prefix topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get the correct result if I remove the braces as suggested by egreg in various places and add the missing underscore in the definition of the prefix:

```
\tl_const:Nn \c_prefix_tl {g_amod_}
```

I found out that the underscore is missing by adding

```
 \edef\test{\tl_use:N \c_prefix_tl #1 \tl_use:N \c_postfix_tl} 
 \show\test
```

in the body of the MakeBool command to see the actual name of the created boolean.